# Hurricane - trajectory in a logarithmic spiral

Tags: kinematics, rotational-kinematics, angular-velocity, weather

Let $f : [0,\infty[ \longrightarrow [0,\infty[$ be a given function and consider a particle on the plane such that

- the particle starts at point $p_0$ at time $t=0$,
- its trajectory $t \mapsto p_t $ is given by a [logarithmic spiral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_spiral) with center $o=(0,0)$ and
- its tangential velocity at time $t$ is $f(\|p_t\|)$.

What's the formula for the position $p_t$ of the particle at time $t>0$?

*Background: I'm trying to trace a particle caught by a hurricane/typhoon/cyclone. In this case $f$ has gamma probability distribution shape.*

Comment: I'm assuming when you say "tangential velocity" you mean tangential speed, or magnitude of tangential velocity.  Are you basically asking to follow the path along a logarithmic spiral some distance, and then find its position?  Are you also providing the pitch of the spiral? (I haven't run all the numbers, but I do believe that pitch is an independent variable here that can't simply be solved for)

Comment: Yes, the magnitude of the tangential velocity vector and the position on the spiral path is required. The pitch should follow from the given velocity.

Comment: Ahh, I see what I was missing.  There's a constraint between f and $\dot p$.  I was thinking of f as a function of time, rather than being a function of radial position.

Comment: @CortAmmon:  I think you were right the first time (unless I've misunderstood the problem.)  See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that the particle's $r$ and $\phi$ coordinates are functions of time, related by $r = a e^{k \phi}$ (or $\phi = \frac{1}{k} \ln(r/a)$.)  The tangential velocity of the particle is then related to the radial velocity by
$$
v_\text{tan} = r \dot{\phi} = r \left( \frac{1}{k} \frac{\dot{r}}{r} \right) = \frac{\dot{r}}{k}.
$$
We are told that this is equal to $f(r)$, so we have the differential equation
$$
f(r) = \frac{1}{k} \frac{dr}{dt},
$$
which is in principle separable;  formally this answer would be the inversion of
$$
k t = \int_{r_0}^r \frac{dr'}{f(r')}.
$$
where $r_0 \equiv \|p_0\|$ in your notation.
For $f(r) \propto e^{-\beta r} r^{\alpha-1}$ (the PDF for a gamma distribution), the integral will be expressed in terms of [incomplete gamma functions.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_functions)  It does not seem likely that a closed-form inverse function will exist, except for special values of the PDF parameters.

Note that the pitch of the spiral is freely specifiable in this solution;  there are no constraints imposed on it by the form of $f$.  Roughly, this occurs because no matter the pitch of the spiral, the particle can always "match" the tangential velocity required of it at a given radius by traversing the spiral faster or slower.

Comment: I thought the pitch follows from the assumptions, but it seems to be a variable.

Comment: Maybe one can find a better profile $f$ looking like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJhbd.png  such that there is an explicit solution.

Comment: Using $f(r) = e^{-r}$ results in $r$ being an increasing function in $t$, such that the particle gets swirled out. That's weird. Maybe $v_{\text{tan}}$ needs a negative sign.

Comment: @JHT:  Yes, without any statement about which way the particle was moving on the spiral, I implicitly assumed that the particle was moving counter-clockwise ($\dot{\phi} > 0$).  If you assume $k > 0$ as well, that leads to $\dot{r}>0$.   You can flip the sign of $k$ or $t$ and get another solution with the same properties.